# Qt Creator не видит QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

Я учусь работать с QtCreator и на данный момент возникла проблема: QtCreator не видит библиотеку `Qwidget` (на самом деле он не видит гораздо больше: все что описано в этом вопросе относится и к `QApplication`, `QLabel`, `QLineEdit` и т.д., но для простоты я буду писать только про `Qwidget`). Но не видит он ее по странному, потому что при попытке `#include <QWidget>`, Qt выдаст `'QWidget' file not found`, и все что в коде будет относится к `Qwidget`, он будет всячески ругать. Но(!) несмотря на это, проект собирается, запускается и работает.

Проблема заключается в том, что при этом весь редактор залит красным цветом - код становится абсолютно нечитаемым, не работает подсветка синтаксиса, автодополнение и т.д. В таких условиях можно писать код только до первой реальной ошибки. Собственно в этом и заключается проблема - Qt в редакторе делает вид, что он не видит `QWidget`,чем сильно затрудняет работу, но на самом деле все он видит...

Я пробовал переустанавливать Qt, сам файл `QWidget` в директориях Qt присутствует (`C:\Qt\6.3.0\mingw_64\include\`), в `.pro` файле строка `QT += widgets` - присутствует. Также я пробовал отправлять своей проект знакомым, у которых также есть Qt - у них все корректно отображается. Также я пробовал полностью удалить Qt со своего компьютера и вместо стандартной установки перенести целиком папку Qt с компьютеров других людей, у которых все работает корректно.

Все эти меры не дали никаких результатов. Поэтому я уже не знаю как я могу решить эту проблему...

Comment: отключайте анализатор и clang в Help/About Plugins...

Comment: Ааааааа! Большое спасибо! Сколько статей/форумов/видео я перерыл и вообще нигде ни слова про это не было сказано. Наконец-то получилось починить Qt, а то я уже не первую неделю с ним воюю. Этот вопрос был последней надеждой, казалось, что уже все что можно перепробовал.

Еще раз огромное вам спасибо!